# "resource" is missing, with no default in R and DBPedia

Tags: r, dbpedia

This may be very simple and perhaps I am missing something obvious. 
I was recently recommended to work with DBPedia to extract some semantic information about the articles in Wikipedia. 
The only thing I am doing now is loading the library as said in 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/querying-dbpedia-from-r/ .
But I have an error in the second line and have no clue how to solve it.
I will really appreciate if someone could help me.

```
> library(datamart)
> dbp <- dbpedia()
```

> Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
>         argument "resource" is missing, with no default

Comment: I could replicate your error. I'm guessing this is a bug, as when looking at the source-code 'dbpedia' appears to be a wrapper for `xsparql`, which needs a `resource` argument (but that isn't specified).

Comment: Any other way of accessing dbPedia?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. Just wanted to let you know the error could be repliated, so it's not something you're doing wrong. It's even described int he latest version of the manual of the `datamart`-package.